# Change jQuery object property

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, dom, firebug

I have this jQuery Object:

[image]

The object called by `$('#demoForm').data();` method and inspected by DOM tab of Firebug.

How do i change highlighted property value? and what the name of topic related to this case?

Comment: Do you mean `window.formwizard.options.focusFirstInput = false`?

Comment: So, you solved the problem?

Comment: @Mr_Green Nope, that doesn't work,

Comment: "Nope, that doesn't work" -- makes no sense. Any error in console? First of all, I can't understand what you want actually.. Please explain clearly.

Comment: It said `TypeError: window.formwizard is undefined`

Comment: I think you should not manipulate the `data` object yourself, the jquery plugin you are using doesn't allow setting this option?